# Is this a correct way to protect my data by AES?

Tags: c++, cryptography, crypto++

```
#include <aes.h>
#include <filters.h>
#include <gcm.h>
#include <osrng.h>

#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string encrypt_data(std::string const &data, byte *iv, byte *key,
                         size_t key_size = CryptoPP::AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH)
{
    CryptoPP::GCM<CryptoPP::AES>::Encryption encryptor;        
    encryptor.SetKeyWithIV(key, key_size, iv);

    std::string ciphertext;
    CryptoPP::StringSource( data, true,
                            new CryptoPP::AuthenticatedEncryptionFilter(
                                encryptor,
                                new CryptoPP::StringSink(ciphertext)
                                )
                            );

    return ciphertext;
}

std::string decrypt_data(std::string const &data, byte *iv, byte *key,
                         size_t key_size = CryptoPP::AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH)
{
    CryptoPP::GCM<CryptoPP::AES>::Decryption decryptor;
    decryptor.SetKeyWithIV(key, key_size, iv);

    std::string recovered;
    CryptoPP::StringSource( data, true,
                            new CryptoPP::AuthenticatedDecryptionFilter(
                                decryptor,
                                new CryptoPP::StringSink( recovered )
                                )
                            );

    return recovered;
}

int main()
{
    try{
        byte key[CryptoPP::AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH];
        byte iv[CryptoPP::AES::BLOCKSIZE];
        CryptoPP::AutoSeededRandomPool rnd;
        rnd.GenerateBlock(key, CryptoPP::AES::BLOCKSIZE);
        rnd.GenerateBlock(iv, CryptoPP::AES::BLOCKSIZE);
        std::string const PlainText = "I love metal gear solid";
        std::string const Encrypted = encrypt_data(PlainText, iv, key);
        std::string const Decrypted = decrypt_data(Encrypted, iv, key);
        std::cout<<std::boolalpha<<(PlainText == Decrypted)<<std::endl;
    }catch(std::exception const &ex){
        std::cerr<<ex.what()<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

Is this a correct way to provide confidentiality and integrity?After study some of the materials of crypto++ and cryptography, I am still very confusing about it. I plan to store the iv in the database, and split the contents of key into different locations of hard disk(hide the key messages in a bunch of files).

edit :
By now my goal is protect the password of the application, the password will be the same on every machines(the database need to synchronize).

Why AES but not PBKDF2?
The clients want us to use ACE/3DES to protect the password, it is the requirement.

Comment: As per my experience with AES it has some block size issue...
Need to do encryption by using loop and by dividing the data stream to the separate blocks.
please Do correct me if I am wrong..

Comment: I think crypto++ already take care those chores for us?

Comment: Any kind of encryption is only as strong as the key. Taking into account your key management policy, the answer to your question is no. Related: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/09/27/keep-it-secret-keep-it-safe.aspx

Comment: @AnkitB OK, I'll correct you :) AES does not have "block size issues" when used in counter mode, and GCM uses CTR mode of operation for the encryption part.

Comment: @ntoskrnl That's one of the articles that anybody involved with crypto should know about. Very well explained. User, you are better off supplying the key at startup, and not keeping it in persistent storage, if anywhere possible. If you only need decryption once in a while, encrypt using a public key (using hybrid cryptography).

Comment: @owlstead I need to decrypt the password many times(I am studying crypto and learn that use encrypt and decrypt type algo to protect password is not a good idea, but this is a request).Thanks for yours help

Comment: @owlstead can you please elaborate more about this?